# Selecting radio button when labels are not set in CSS using xpath locator

Tags: html, xpath, automated-tests, robotframework

Not able to select radio buttons using ride (robot framework) for below `HTML` tags using `xpath` locator in `robotframework`.

```
<Pre>    
    <div class="controls">
      <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The isPdfFormat field is required." id="isPdfFormat" name="isPdfFormat" value="true" type="radio"></input> PDF 
      <input checked="checked" id="isPdfFormat" name="isPdfFormat" value="false" type="radio"></input> CSV    
    </div>
</Pre>
```

Comment: which radio button? 1st or 2nd ? `xpath` can be used to do so.

Comment: 2nd one ? Can you please provide me X-path for same. Let me know if xpath=//input[@id='isPdfFormat'][contains(text(),'CSV')] will work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below **xpath**:
`//input[normalize-space(following-sibling::text())='CSV' and @id='isPdfFormat']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Xpath for selecting the first radio button

```
(.//*[@class='controls']/input)[1]
```

If you want to select second one use this

```
(.//*[@class='controls']/input)[2]
```

If the class is not unique and there are more elements with the matching class, try using the Id

```
(.//*[@id='isPdfFormat'])[1]
```